# Correct way to reference modules from other modules in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm writing a module for NodeJS in Typescript. I'm trying to process a request (which should be an IncomingMessage object) using this module.

```ts
/// <reference path="typings/node/node.d.ts"/>
module rateLimiter {
  export function processRequest(req : http.IncomingMessage) : Boolean {
    return false;
  };
}
```

When attempting to ensure that the incoming request parameter `req` is such an instance, I find that I cannot reference anything from the http module. I think to myself "okay, so I need to import it because that's just an alias". When I do so however, I receive "import delcarations in a namespace cannot reference a module."

```ts
/// <reference path="typings/node/node.d.ts"/>
module rateLimiter {
  import http = require('http');//IMPORT DECLARATIONS IN A NAMESPACE CANNOT REFERENCE A MODULE
  export function processRequest(req : http.IncomingMessage) : Boolean {
    return false;
  };
}
```

So I try what seems like a poor decision, importing in the global scope, only to receive "cannot compile modules unless --module flag is provided"

```ts
/// <reference path="typings/node/node.d.ts"/>
  import http = require('http');//CANNOT COMPILE MODULES UNLESS --MODULE FLAG IS PROVIDED
module rateLimiter {
  export function processRequest(req : http.IncomingMessage) : Boolean {
    return false;
  };
}
```

I feel like I'm fundamentally missing how this sort of reference is supposed to be made. It feels like I shouldn't have to import a module just to use the definitions included in node.d.ts. Could someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing a module, nothing you write is in the global scope - the file itself is a module, and everything inside it is scoped to that module.

```
import http = require('http');

export function processRequest(req : http.IncomingMessage) : boolean {
    return false;
};
```

In the example above, the file, `rateLimiter.ts` is the module. `http` is imported into the `rateLimiter` module.

You need to compile with the module flag - for example:

```
tsc --module commonjs rateLimiter.ts
```

Most editors and IDEs supply a way to set this too.

Comment: Sorry. You're right about the scoping phrasing. I guess when put like that it makes sense semantically too. Appreciated!